# Django @permission_required Decorator not Working in function-based view

Tags: django, permissions, user-permissions

I was trying to give permission a user that he can do everything except delete. He has view permission

here is my function

```
@login_required(login_url='loginPage')
@permission_required('excel_data.view_exceldata', raise_exception=True)
def viewExcel(request):
    excelInfo = ExcelData.objects.filter(deleted=0).order_by('-pk')
    return render(request, 'excelData.html', {'excelInfo': excelInfo})
```

here is my **auth_permission** database table view 
[image]

here is my **auth_user_user_permissions** table view

[image]

here is my **add_permission** function

```
def add_permission(request):
    user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=request.POST.get('username'),
            email=request.POST.get('email'),
            password=request.POST.get('password'),
            is_staff=1,
            is_superuser=0,
        )
    permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can view excel data')
    user.user_permissions.add(permission)
    user.save()
```

in my **auth_user** table

> is_superuser = 0 , is_staff = 1 , is_active = 1

when I try to view that page I got **403 Forbidden** what is I'm doing wrong

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are you sure your user has `is_active` set to `True`?

Comment: I just update my question please have look

Comment: You have a typo in `value = request.POST.get('permition')` -> "permition" vs "permission". Also, what are AuthPermission and AuthUserUserPermission models? They are not standard django models. `@permission_required` decorator looks built in `Permission` model from the `django.contrib.auth` app

Comment: thanks for your comment I update my permission code for when a user will create. I try to give view permission like this but still not working.